# How to divide a polygon into tiny polygons of a particular size?

Tags: python, mathematical-optimization, arcgis, qgis, pyqgis

I would like to divide/cut an irregular polygon into tiny polygons of a particular size(1.6m x 1m) in such a way that most of the irregular polygon area has to be utilized (an OPTIMIZATION MODEL)

The length and width of the polygon can be interchanged (either 1.6m X 1m (or) 1m X 1.6m)

So, in the end, I need to have as many polygons of size (1.6m X 1m) as possible.

You may consider it as a packing problem. I need to pack as many rectangles of size(1.6m x 1m) as possible inside a polygon. The rectangles can be translated and rotated but not intersect each other.
[image]

I used the "Create Grid" feature but it just cuts the whole polygon in a particular fashion.
[image]

But what I also want is that here, a blue polygon can also be cut in a vertical manner(1m x 1.6m) too.
[image]

So, I would like to know whether there is a plugin for this in QGIS/ArcGIS or any python script for this kind of polygon optimization?

Comment: You might be better of asking in mathematics if such an optimal tiling actually exists. Some more questions: Do you only consider rectangular polygons or looking for a general solution? Do you consider only regular tilings (with integer translation and x*90° rotation)...?

Comment: You may consider it as a packing problem. I need to pack as many rectangles of size(1.6m x 1m) as possible inside a polygon. The rectangles can be translated and rotated.